# Ethash Algorithm, Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I have problems in finding the documents about the block header of Ethereum as well as the input for the Ethash (length, etc..) and how to get the data of block header Ethereum. Can you help me find them and put them in this topic? I really expect from you. Thanks all.

Comment: Here you can find a very good explanation: [Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture)